# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUTC produce different output then TimeZone.BaseUTCOffset

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I have a UTC date-time, I need to convert it to EST time zone. It should be as simple as this

```
 var easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
 var dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc);            
 return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, easternZone);
```

So my input date is

> 02-08-2019 22:53:32

and the result value is

> 02-08-2019 18:53:32

It deduct 4 hours from given time.

But if I check the Offset between Eastern Standard Time Zone and UTC time zone then the value it return is

> easternZone.BaseUtcOffset {-05:00:00} System.TimeSpan

If this is true then above result value should be

> 02-08-2019 17:53:32

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Did you check if the `TimeZoneInfo` you got is on daylight savings?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, I tried my best to answer it: There is actually no problem in your code, [the difference between UTC and EST is actually 4 hours.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=difference%20between%20EST%20and%20UTC) But, if you need the difference to be 5 hours then use Central Standard Time (CST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure what I am missing here.

[`BaseUtcOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.baseutcoffset?view=netframework-4.8) does not take into account daylight saving time (it can't, since it doesn't know what specific date you are interested in). You likely want to use [`GetUtcOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getutcoffset?view=netframework-4.8):

> The returned time span includes any differences due to the application
> of adjustment rules to the current time zone. It differs from the
> BaseUtcOffset property, which returns the difference between
> Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) and the time zone's standard time
> and, therefore, does not take adjustment rules into account.

**Adjustment Rule** is discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule?view=netframework-4.8) (emphasis mine):

> Provides information about a time zone adjustment, **such as the**
> **transition to and from daylight saving time.**

*As a general rule, if dates are ever <= 1 hour out from what you expect, look into daylight savings issues.*

To illustrate the impact of daylight saving time:

```
var timeUtc = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-2019 22:53:32");
var easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(timeUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc);            
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, easternZone));
Console.WriteLine(easternZone.GetUtcOffset(dt));

timeUtc = Convert.ToDateTime("07-07-2019 22:53:32");
easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(timeUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc);            
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, easternZone));
Console.WriteLine(easternZone.GetUtcOffset(dt));
```

The above code will output:

```
1/1/2019 5:53:32 PM
-05:00:00
7/7/2019 6:53:32 PM
-04:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
var timeUtc = Convert.ToDateTime("02-08-2019 22:53:32");
TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);
Console.WriteLine(easternTime);
```